# Android emulator settings stops when opening storage tab

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-debug

I am developing an android app in which I have an broadcast receiver for sd card related intents like mount ,removed e.t.c.

So for debugging purpose when I am opening storage tab of android settings for mounting and unmounting of sd card it gives me message **"Unfortunately setting has stopped"**.

So not understanding this wired behaviour why it is happening so why it is closing. Why I am not able to open it.

See this screen shot

[image]

**Here is the stackTrace**

[image]

Comment: @njzk2 see my updated post. I have posted stacktrace.

Answer (score -1):

Delete and create new Aandroid virtual device [Emulator]